# Why Jenkins returning http 500 while adding git repository?

Tags: github, jenkins, http-status-code-500

I am trying to add a git repository in a freestyle job. However after adding the repository, seeing the error described in the snip provided. [image: HTTP 500 error]

Answer (score 2):

In Jenkins, go to *Manage Jenkins* > *Global Tool Configuration* > *Git*. There, determine the path to `git.exe` from just that to something like `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`—or wherever you have your `git.exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error. Please use Java Version 11 instead of Java Version 8. Also, install only the suggested plugins for Git.

Comment: What are the suggested plugins for git?

Answer (score 0):

You better check out your Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration. There you need to look at your `JAVA_HOME` value and the Path to Git executable. I'm using the Docker image with these values:

- JAVA_HOME: /opt/java/openjdk
- Path to Git executable: git